# javascript file does not trigger in php

Tags: javascript, php

php:

```
<?php
if (empty($itemId)|| (empty($title) && $title==="Please Select") 
   || empty($subtitle) || empty($descript)
    ||   empty($availability)
    || empty($price) || empty($filename))
  {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    'emptyfield()';
    echo "</script>";
  }
>?
```

javascript:

```
 function emptyfield()
 {
if(document.forms ["add"] ["save"].value !== "")


 {

   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML="Please fill the blank fields!!!";

 }
 }
```

> The java script file does not trigger in the php file.  When I click the submit button, I need the div to be displayed as "Please fill the blank fields".  But it does not happen in my case.

Comment: give more code detail. Here we can't even see the formular your are talking about. and simply said what is your problem. It's unclear to me

Comment: Echoing a small script like this isn't going to pop up some text in an existing page since the browser is already reloading the page. It's not clear from what you've posted how these snippets are supposed to fit together, but it doesn't look to me like this will ever work, even allowing for the missing `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, You have did a error in PHP end tag `?>` as well as change the script as how i mentioned.

```
<?php
if (empty($itemId)|| (empty($title) && $title==="Please Select") 
   || empty($subtitle) || empty($descript)
    ||   empty($availability)
    || empty($price) || empty($filename))
  {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">emptyfield()</script>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
'emptyfield()';
echo "</script>";
```

I think you forgot to echo the `'emptyfield()';` in php.

Comment: Simply change `'emptyfield()';` to `echo 'emptyfield()';`

Answer (score 0):

You're not echoing the `emptyfield();` line.

Troubleshooting problems like this would be as simple as viewing source of the rendered markup in your browser, and you'd see that this line doesn't get written to the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the checking after data was posted

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST']=='POST'){
   // checking condition
    $condition = (empty($itemId)|| (empty($title) && $title==="Please Select") 
      || empty($subtitle) 
      || empty($descript)
      ||   empty($availability)
      || empty($price) 
      || empty($filename)); 

    if($condition){
    // Throw an error here!
    echo "Please fill all the tables"; 

    }else{
    // execute query here.

    }
}
```

or if you want to use client side checking of inputs
create a function in javascript to check their value

```
function checkIfBlank(form){
   for(x in form){ 
   //checking only input boxes, select boxes and textarea
   if(form[x].nodeName=='INPUT' || form[x].nodeName=='SELECT' || form[x].nodeName=='TEXTAREA'){
      //checking of value if its empty.. if empty throw error
         if(form[x].value==''){
            if(document.getElementById(form[x].id)!=null){
            alert("Please enter a value in the fields with red borders.");

            document.getElementById(form[x].id).style.border="inset 3px red";
            document.getElementById(form[x].id).focus();

            return false;
            }
   }

}

}
```

In the form you should do like this

```
<form name='myForm' type='post' action='yourphp.php' onsubmit='return checkIfBlank(this.form)' >
 //elements here..

</form>
```

Explanation:

When submitting the form, or hitting the submit button, `checkIfBlank` javascript function will be called passing the form `myForm` as its argument. 
`checkIfBlank` function then checks each element in `myForm` if it has a value. `if not` then highlights the element with red borders then focus on it then return false, which means the form will not be submitted. if `all elements have value` then it will return nothing thus proceeding in the submission of data.